# What does "It's I'll be here" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found a [song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Boy#Lyrics) where I don't understand the meaning of *it is*:

> Or when the valley's hushed and white with snow,
>
> **It's I'll be here in sunshine or in shadow**,

and

> The summer's gone, and all the roses falling,
>
> It's you, **it's you must go and I must bide**.

What does this *it's* mean?

I suppose it could be similar to *this is,* or *it means*. Am I correct?

Comment: It's not standard English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an omitted relative pronoun in each of these lines.

> It's you, it's you <s>***who***</s> must go and I <s>***who***</s> must bide.
>   It's I <s>***who***</s> will be here in sunshine or in shadow...

Today omitting the relative pronoun is common only when it stands for the object of the verb in the relative clause:

> It's you <s>***who***</s> I want to see.

But in older English omitting a subject relative was common, and that use survives in dialect and much colloquial use:

> You know the people <s>***who***</s> own the house on the corner?

The author employs this obsolete syntax to lend his song a traditional flavor, just as he uses the obsolete pronoun *ye*, and the obsolete 'subjunctive' *tread* in the fourth verse, and sets the song to an old Irish air.

Answer (score 1):

*It's* is simply used here to describe a situation, not much different from **it's** a sunny day. However, what follows is not standard.

You could read it as follows (I put the verses in order):

> It's you, it's you must go and I must bide.
>   becomes
>   **It is now like this**: it is *you* that has to go and I will have to stay

and the second verse:

> But come ye back when summer's in the meadow,
>   Or when the valley's hushed and white with snow,
>   It's I'll be here in sunshine or in shadow,
>   becomes
>   But if you come back, when it's summer,
>   Or when the valley is quiet and white with snow,
>   **It will be like this**: I will be here (with you) in good or bad times,

So the song describes the current situation, and a promise of a future (possible?) situation, that *if* the beloved returns, the situation will be different.